# Библиотека fastapi-users установлена, но pycharm её не видит

Tags: python, pycharm, fastapi

Зашёл в виртуальное окружение

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

Установил fast_api users

```
pip install 'fastapi-users[sqlalchemy]'
```

Вставил код из документации

```
from typing import AsyncGenerator

from fastapi import Depends
from fastapi_users.db import SQLAlchemyBaseUserTable, SQLAlchemyUserDatabase
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
....
```

Pycharm всё равно не видит, подсвечивает красным
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай вот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В общем не знаю что там было. Решил проблему сбросив настройки по умолчанию

Из главного меню
**File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажал **Restore and Restart.**

Pycharm перезапустился, открыл вновь проект,около 5 минут он индексировался. И всё заработало.